# Web scraping. Press "Show more" button. What is the tag behind the "Show more" button?

Tags: html, css, r

I am trying to scrape all app reviews on Google Play. The problem is that after loading the reviews page scroll down 4 times, the "Show more" button appears, but I don't know how to press it and run again 4 more times and so on until you reach the bottom of the page.

```
 #scroll down 10 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
  for(i in 1:10){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
  remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc")$clickElement()  
  Sys.sleep(5)    
  }
```

Since I don't know the HTML tag that is related to the "Show more" button

This is the page where the button I want to press is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&showAllReviews=true

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  You can right click and choose Inspect Element and it will jump to and highlight the corresponding element in the page source.

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome. I have already done this but the problem is that I cannot identify the element corresponding to the "Show more" button